# What is the right way of using sprite image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Let's say we have requirement that icon image element need to present in HTML because we need to indicate icon existence for some screen readers and it's better to have them like IMG tag than I or plain DIV.

We have `sprite.png` and `empty.png` images. empty.png used for creating fake blank image (sprite image will be shown because it's background of our element).

In css we have class

```
.icon {
    background:url('sprite.png') 0px 0px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Then we use this in our HTML like this:

```
<img src="empty.png" class="icon" alt="Image from Sprite is Shown" />
```

Can we do it any other way, using our 'sprite.png' as image source with setting any mask/clip property on img with css?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`background-image` does not take the 0px parameters you have after it. You may be mixing it up with `background`.

To show the correct portion of the sprite image, you use `background-position` to select the correct portion of the image.

Here is a simple tutorial page: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-sprites.php

Comment: Not answer for the question, but thanks for the notice - will change.